# How to use multilevel and hashed categorical variables to build an anomaly detection classifier

Tags: machine-learning

I am building a binary classifier to detect hacker intrusions from a network. My dataset has over 20K events, of which 4% are positive (intrusions) and the rest are safe events. I am attempting to use random forests to build the classifier, but most of my variables are categorical variables (i.e., IP addresses) with over 19K levels. Moreover, the data is hashed, so I don't have the actual IP addresses, but its hashed numbers. I considered one hot encoding these variables, but this would result in 19k different variables, or reducing the dimensionality of these variables, but given that they are hashed, I don't think I can do this.

Further, I understand that hashing an input could result in two ore more IP addresses associated with a single hash numbers, therefore preventing me using the hash number to discern between safe and unsafe IP addresses (the same hash could in theory be given to both). Is there any way around this?

I have other data to work with, but they don't seem to be working that well when attempting, for example, logistic regression. I am considering other methods like weighted logistic regression or maybe an outlier detector, but I haven't used one before.

Comment: What hashing algorithm was used (or what do the final hashes look like?)

Comment: Just like long alphanumerical strings of around 200 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of your question seems to be whether a hash of an IP address can be used as a replacement for the IP address itself or if this will not perfectly differentiate the IP addresses (due to hash collisions).

Let's assume you are using SHA-1 hashes, which have 160 bits in the hashed value (and therefore $2^{160}$ different hash values). The probability that $k = 19,000$ hashes randomly selected from the set of $N=2^{160}$ possible hashes are all unique is:

$$\frac{N-1}{N}\frac{N-2}{N}\ldots\frac{N-(k-1)}{N}$$

This means the collision probability is roughly $10^{-39.9}$, meaning it is vanishingly unlikely that you would have a hash collision, and you can almost certainly safely use the hashes in place of the real IP addresses.

Comment: great answer, thanks! would this significantly change if a different (but also commonly used) function was used?

Comment: @user3824382 Hash functions are designed to make collisions very unlikely, so unless a very weak hash function were used (e.g. CRC32), you should be fine. Given that you stated that your hashes were "long alphanumerical strings of around 200 characters" in your comment on the question, my guess is that hash collisions should be vanishingly unlikely in your case.